# SQL split consumption full Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, recursive-query

I have a problem. I would like to split a value for a full month.

I have the daily consumption and the Starts and End Dates like in the example:

[image: Problem]

And I would like to split the value for each month between Start and End Date like this:

[image: Result]

I need to do this for make some calculations per month.

Comment: What is it you need help with? What are you asking? What have you tried, and why didn't it work? Please do ask us a question, so that we can give you an answer. Also, please do take the time to supply sample data, and results, as tabular formatted `text`. it really helps us help you.

Comment: Best to post sample data and desired results as text (not images).

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        customer, 
        averageDailyConsumption, 
        startDate, 
        case when endDate > eomonth(startDate) 
            then eomonth(startDate)  
            else endDate 
        end endDate,
        endDate originalEndDate
    from mytable
    union all 
    select 
        customer, 
        averageDailyConsumption,
        dateadd(day, 1, endDate) startDate,
        case when originalEndDate > eomonth(dateadd(day, 1, endDate)) 
            then eomonth(dateadd(day, 1, endDate))
            else originalEndDate
        end,
        originalEndDate
    from cte
    where originalEndDate > endDate
)
select customer, averageDailyConsumption, startDate, endDate
from cte 
order by customer, startDate
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4358c1c571a4461d8ce401a7bf42a725)**:

```
customer | averageDailyConsumption | startDate  | endDate   
-------: | :---------------------- | :--------- | :---------
       3 | 578.67                  | 2019-10-02 | 2019-10-16
       3 | 85.94                   | 2019-10-17 | 2019-10-31
       3 | 85.94                   | 2019-11-01 | 2019-11-30
       3 | 85.94                   | 2019-12-01 | 2019-12-17
       3 | 95.97                   | 2019-12-18 | 2019-12-31
       3 | 95.97                   | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-31
       3 | 95.97                   | 2020-02-01 | 2020-02-13
```

---

Here is a workaround SQL Server < 2012, where `eomonth()` is not supported:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        customer, 
        averageDailyConsumption, 
        startDate, 
        case when endDate > dateadd(month, ((year(startDate) - 1900) * 12) + month(startDate), -1)
            then cast(dateadd(month, ((year(startDate) - 1900) * 12) + month(startDate), -1) as date)
            else endDate 
        end endDate,
        endDate originalEndDate
    from mytable
    union all 
    select 
        customer, 
        averageDailyConsumption,
        dateadd(day, 1, endDate) startDate,
        case when originalEndDate > dateadd(month, ((year(dateadd(day, 1, endDate)) - 1900) * 12) + month(dateadd(day, 1, endDate)), -1)
            then cast(dateadd(month, ((year(dateadd(day, 1, endDate)) - 1900) * 12) + month(dateadd(day, 1, endDate)), -1) as date)
            else originalEndDate
        end,
        originalEndDate
    from cte
    where originalEndDate > endDate
)
select customer, averageDailyConsumption, startDate, endDate
from cte 
order by customer, startDate
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9afdb3cd1c6435f4fb5102606d99ff66)**

Comment: Hello GMB, And thanks for your answer. I've tried you example, amb I have problems because I using a SQL Server 2008 R2 and the function EOMONTH() is not available.

Comment: I was thinking to create a DataRange, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: @Cambrix: I updated my answer with a workaround for versions of SQL Server that do not support `eomonth()`.